# C# Find the Selected State of all items in a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selecteditem

I have found many examples on how to find the selected items in a listbox and how to iterate through a listbox;

```
for(int index=0;index < listBox1.Items.Count; index++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
}
```

or

```
foreach (DataRowView item in listBox1.Items)
{
   MessageBox.Show(item.Row["ID"].ToString() + " | " + item.Row["bus"].ToString());
}
```

While these methods work great for the selected items, what I have yet to figure out, or find, is how to get the selected state, selected and unselected, of every item in a listbox, as the above only gives the selected. 
Basically, I need something like this;

```
for(int index=0;index < listBox1.Items.Count; index++)
{
    if (index.SelectedMode == SelectedMode.Selected)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Items[index].ToString() +"= Selected";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Items[index].ToString() +"= Unselected";
    }
}
```

I've found a snippet that said to use (listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1) to determine the selected state however I've not figured out or found how to build a loop around this to check each item in the listbox.

I've also read that I should put the listbox items into an array, but again nothing about getting the selected state of each item in the listbox.

I know I'll have to iterate through the listbox to accomplish what I'm needing, pretty sure it'll be one of the above loops, however I have yet to find how to extract the selected state of each item in the listbox.

I'm using VS2013, C# Windows Form, .NET Framework 4.0
Thanks in advance for any advice/direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the unselected items:

```
List<string> unselected = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Except(listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<string>());
```

You can loop over that list like this:

```
foreach(string str in listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Except(listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<string>()))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{str} = Not selected");
}
```

I've made the assumption that you're using `string` as your item type. If you want to use something else then just replace `string` with your type and it should still work.

You then loop over the unselected items to do whatever you want with them then loop over `listBox1.SelectedItems` to do whatever you want with the selected ones.

Comment: This looks like an interesting approach and I will take a closer look at it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Could you explain why it's not correct? I was missing the $ from the WriteLine which I've added in but I don't see anything else wrong with it - I've tested this code and it works.

Comment: The item can be anything, for example in the question, items are `DataRowView`. To get the text from an item you should use `GetItemText` method of `ListBox`. For example, to get text of all items, you can use `listBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Select(x=>listBox1.GetItemText(x))`.

Comment: As I said in my answer I assumed a string but said it could be switched out for a different type. Changing the cast from `<string>` to `<DataRowView>` still works fine - the only other change is that `{str}` needs to be updated to include the text property of DataRowView. My answer is still correct.

Comment: After closer review and comparison of the two answers, this provided me more information about the control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GetSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.getselected?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of the `ListBox`. It returns a value indicating whether the specified item is selected.

For example, the following code, sets the value of `selected` to `true` if the item at index 0 (the first item) is selected:

```
var selected = listBox1.GetSelected(0);
```

**Example**

Te following loop, shows a message box for each item, showing the item text and item selection status:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.Items[i]);
    var selected = listBox1.GetSelected(i);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}:{1}", text, selected ? "Selected" : "Not Selected"));
}
```

Comment: This answer got me much closer and does identify the selected/unselected however how can I incorporate pulling the value of the item being evaluated as the code loops?

Comment: I have
string itm = "";
                for(int index = 0; index < listBox1.Items.Count; index++)
                {
                    itm = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
                    if (listBox1.GetSelected(index) == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Selected: " + itm);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not Selected: " + itm);
                    }
                }

Comment: I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Reza Aghaei, your added example does exactly what I need. Thank you very much!